# Return codes in Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, return-value

Suppose I am writing a function in Scala, which returns a *return code*: `SUCCESS`, `ERROR1`, `ERROR2`, ... (note that is different from `scala.util.Either`)

Obviously, I can create an hierarchy to represent the *return code* as follows:

```
trait ReturnCode
case object Success extends ReturnCode
case object Error1 extends ReturnCode
case object Error2 extends ReturnCode
...
```

Now I wonder if there is a "standard" idiomatic solution in Scala for that.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use `Either` or `Try`?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about scala.util.Try.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Try`, as an alternative to `Either`. The "left" value is fixed to `Throwable` and it is right-biased, which means, that map/flatMap etc will only be executed on a success and exceptions are kept as they are, just like wirh `Some` and `None` for `Option`. You can use `Try.apply` around a block to catch non fatal exceptions and wrap the result in a `Try`.

Comment: What if my failure is not always a `Throwable`? How can I use `Try` in that case?

Comment: In that case you can create your own exception type. The benefit of using `Try` is that you can chain your operations and then at the end handle the errors.

Comment: Thanks. I will think of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sealed`](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/123) keyword.

```
sealed trait ReturnCode
case object Success extends ReturnCode
case object Error1 extends ReturnCode
case object Error2 extends ReturnCode
```

You'll get a warning if you'll forget some of codes:

```
scala> def test(r: ReturnCode) = r match {
     |   case Success => "Success"
     |   case Error1 => "Error1"
     | }
<console>:1: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Error2
       def test(r: ReturnCode) = r match {
```